# Cloud Functions: How to send a daily email at 10am with an extract of a table?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

New to GCP Cloud Functions, and I am wanting to send a daily email at 10am, which would contain an extract of a specific table in BigQuery.

So far, I have written my code to send an email; though, I am not sure what to do in order to send the email at 10 am daily alongside the table extract:

```
def email(request):
    import os
    from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
    from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Email
    from python_http_client.exceptions import HTTPError

    sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ['EMAIL_API_KEY'])

    html_content = "<p>Table XYZ is attached here</p>"

    message = Mail(
        to_emails="[Destination]@email.com",
        from_email=Email('[YOUR]@gmail.com', "Your name"),
        subject="Hello world",
        html_content=html_content
        )
    message.add_bcc("[YOUR]@gmail.com")

    try:
        response = sg.send(message)
        return f"email.status_code={response.status_code}"
        #expected 202 Accepted

    except HTTPError as e:
        return e.message
```

Comment: is it possible to trigger your cloud function by a scheduler? - https://cloud.google.com/scheduler

Comment: Yes - though, how would you trigger the Function using Scheduler?